# Radare2 Disassembler How Do You Organize Visual Panels (V!)?

Tags: x86, radare2, static-analysis

I would like to use Radare2 to learn about how C is assembled into assembly but I am having trouble with the layout. I think the V! mode would be very handy as you can watch the registers update as the instruction pointer moves through the program, but I don't understand the layout.

This is an example of they layout I would like: 
[image]

It seems when I add a window (like Stack or Registers in this photo) it appears offscreen and I have to try closing different and splitting windows until the layout kind of falls into place. Is there an easy way to change exactly what is in each window?

I know 'X' closes a window, 'z' switches the current window to the front, and '-' / '|' split a window.

I have tried looking at the help but can't seem to figure out any other commands related to this issue.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. If you literally just want to see how the compiler translates stuff to assembly you may be better off using a compiler (GCC's and Clang's `-S` switch may be helpful here). Additionally you can use the [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) or install your own instance of it (it's open source).

Answer (score 6):

Use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to move between the windows, use <kbd>e</kbd> to change name and command of a specific panel you are on. Use <kbd>w</kbd> to enter the window mode. "Window mode" allows you to control how the panels look like. In window-mode you can use <kbd>HJKL</kbd> to resize the window's height and width.

This should answer your question "Is there an easy way to change exactly what is in each window?". Because you can simply select a panel and use <kbd>e</kbd> to change its content :)

Don't forget to use <kbd>?</kbd> in the different visual screens to get more help